# how to calculate time between receiving variables in swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a variable that will changes every millisecond or so.
I want to calculate the time between them correctly without delay.

I want to know how long takes to get the new one.

Is that possible in swift?
I know that there is a timer in swift but according to apple documentation:

> that's not exact.i need to get the millisecond time between each
>   receiving variable.

Answer (score 3):

Use a property observer `didSet` with `Date` arithmetic to compute the interval between changes.

Here is an example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var setTime: Date?
    private var intervals = [Double]()

    var value: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            let now = Date()
            if let previous = setTime {
                intervals.append(now.timeIntervalSince(previous) * 1000)
            }
            setTime = now
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 1...20 {
            value = i
        }

        print(intervals)
    }

}
```

**Console output**

> [0.0020265579223632812, 0.12600421905517578, 0.00095367431640625, 0.0050067901611328125, 0.0010728836059570312, 0.00095367431640625, 0.00095367431640625, 0.0010728836059570312, 0.00095367431640625, 0.0020265579223632812, 0.00095367431640625, 0.0010728836059570312, 0.00095367431640625, 0.0, 0.0010728836059570312, 0.00095367431640625, 0.00095367431640625, 0.0020265579223632812, 0.0010728836059570312]

Comment: thank you sir, i got the answer that i wanted, that i have to use date or dispatch time , but now i have an oder problem,  i have a pre init variable that i get from a function parameter , that i set  my variable to the function parameter in that function ,each time that the function parameter changes i will get the new variable, and then i have to switch the case that i need and then cache the time between each new value of that case. do you have any idea how to do that ??

Answer (score 1):

You can capture time whenever the value changes and calculate the difference. like:

```
var yourVar: Int {
    willSet {
        //you can capture the time here
    }

    didSet {
        //or here
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to know, which timer to use, which class or api, anyway thanks for your response, but now i have an oder problem, i have a pre init variable that i get from a function parameter , that i set my variable to the function parameter in that function ,each time that the function parameter changes i will get the new variable, and then i have to switch the case that i need and then cache the time between each new value of that case. do you have any idea how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var _variable = 0
var variable : Int {
    get{
        return _variable
    }
    set{
        let start = DispatchTime.now()
        _variable = newValue
        let dst = start.distance(to: DispatchTime.now())
        print("Interval = \(dst)")
    }
}

variable = 1
variable = 2
```

Output:
Interval = nanoseconds(2239301) 
Interval = nanoseconds(69482)

Comment: thank you sir, i got the answer that i wanted, that i have to use dispatch time , but now i have an oder problem,  i have a pre init variable that i get from a function parameter , that i set  my variable to the function parameter in that function ,each time that the function parameter changes i will get the new variable, and then i have to switch the case that i need and then cache the time between each new value of that case. do you have any idea how to do that ??